# case is generating nulls in SQL databricks

Tags: sql, databricks

I have a very simple table with key/value pairs in databricks. I want to move from long to wide just a couple of columns not using PIVOT.
But I always end with Nulls no matter how i do. (i have been checking this very same SQL in some other databases as mysql and everything worked as expected)

```
   CREATE TEMP VIEW channels(id, key, value) AS
       VALUES (1,'channel', 10),
              (1,'version',  20),
              (2,'channel',  30),
              (2,'version',  40),
              (3,'channel', 50),
              (3,'version', 60),
              (4,'channel',  70),
              (4,'version',  80),
              (5,'channel', 95),
              (5,'version',  105);
           
          
select max(id) as id,
case when max(key) = "channel" then max(value)  end as channel
from channels
group by id;
          
id  channel
1   NULL    
2   NULL    
3   NULL    
4   NULL    
5   NULL
```

Expected

```
id  channel
1   10
2   30
3   50
4   70
5   95
```

Comment: Why are you have `max(id)` when you are grouping by it?

Comment: Can’t do it otherwise. An error is raised if you do not aggregate id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation [FILTER clause](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/max.html):

```
select id, MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 'channel') AS channel
from channels
group by id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6d6a304f326b38f2b0ed334c9f12f9f0)**

Answer (score 0):

Put the `case` *expression* inside the `MAX()`:

```
select id,
       max(case when key = "channel" then value end) as channel
from channels
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I too agree @Lukasz answer .

```
%sql
select id, MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 'channel') AS channel
from channels
group by id;
```

[image]